# Telescoping series convergence/divergence with arctan

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Say we have the following series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=5}^\infty (\arctan(n^{-1})-\arctan((n+1)^{-1}))$

I want to determine whether it is convergent or divergent, here's what I tried:

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=5}^\infty (\arctan(n^{-1})-\arctan((n+1)^{-1}))$

$= \displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle \sum_{k=5}^n (\arctan(k^{-1})-\arctan((k+1)^{-1}))$

which is a telescoping series that can be simplified to

$= \displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}(\arctan(5^{-1})-\arctan((n+1)^{-1}))$

= $\arctan(5^{-1})$

And so the series converges to $\arctan(5^{-1})$. Is that correct?

Comment: Please do not vandalise your question or else it will be flagged.

Comment: @TobyMak:  It has been, but with the American spelling of vandalize

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks!

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you put a backslash before common functions, you get the right font and spacing, so \arctan x gives $\arctan x$ instead of arctan x giving $arctan x$  If it doesn't work, \operatorname {function} always works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It might even be more obvious if you write out a few terms. Then

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=5}^\infty \arctan \left( \frac 1 n \right) - \arctan \left( \frac{1}{n+1} \right) = &\;\;\;\; \arctan \left( \frac 1 5 \right) - \arctan \left( \frac 1 6 \right) \\
&+ \arctan \left(  \frac 1 6 \right) - \arctan \left( \frac 1 7 \right) \\
&+ \arctan \left( \frac 1 7 \right) - \arctan \left( \frac 1 8 \right) \\
&+ \cdots\\
\end{align}$$

Obvious cancellation happens along the diagonals, leaving us with $\arctan(1/5)$ ... on the premise it converges! Bear in mind that, for this telescoping method to work, the summands need to converge to $0$ in the infinite limit. Of course, showing that in this case is quite easy, and you have already done so.